# Numpy unpackbits type error when trying to convert bytes to bits

Tags: python, numpy

To get bits from bytes:

```
bytes = bytes([0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00])
bits = numpy.unpackbits(bytes)
```

throws this error:
`TypeError: Expected an input array of unsigned byte data type`
but if I get bytes in this way it works:

```
bytes = numpy.fromfile(filename, dtype="uint8")
```

How to solve this error, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass an array with a `dtype` of unsigned integer:

```
hex_codes = 0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00
arr = np.array(hex_codes).astype(np.uint8)
np.unpackbits(arr)
```

Output:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

Btw, you probably know this, but you should not reassign a builtin as you did with `bytes`.

Answer (score 1):

bytes should be unsigned array, why not use a numpy unsigned?

```
bytearray = numpy.array([0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00],dtype=numpy.uint8)
bits = numpy.unpackbits(bytearray)
```